# Show MasterView first instead of Details

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a splitview with Master (showing table view) and Details (Showing detail data). When I launch my app it shows detailview first with no data but I need to show masterview first.

I know that there are some answers but nothing works for me.

[image: storyboard]

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MySplitViewControllerShowingMasterViewFirst: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but it works now ! Don't know why it didn't work before :D . Thanks a lot